# How can I get appSetting values from a specific config file

Tags: c#, mocking

I'm trying to inject a mock of a configuration reader defined as

```
public interface IConfigurationReader
{
    string GetConfigSetting(string settingName);
}
```

and in the implementation looks like:

```
    private class MyConfig : cherry.Framework.IConfigurationReader
    {
        public string GetConfigSetting(string settingName)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[settingName];
        }
    }
```

The problem is of course this requires me to have an app.config file in this project.  Ideally I want to do something like:

```
return Foo("c:\temp\someconfig.config\",settingName);
```

Is there a built-in method that will take a file name and return the desired setting?

Comment: If you are using a mock, then why do you require an actual config file?

Comment: I'm lazy and want to point the reader to a central config file instead of mocking each setting.

Answer (score 0):

XML to linq was my friend:

```
    private class MyConfig : cherry.Framework.IConfigurationReader
    {
        private String ConfigFile { get; set; }  

        public MyConfig(String configFile)
        {
            ConfigFile = configFile;
        }
        public string GetConfigSetting(string settingName)
        {
            var setting  = XDocument.Load(ConfigFile).Descendants("add").Select(s => new
            {
                AppKey = s.Attribute("key"),
                AppValue = s.Attribute("value")
            }).FirstOrDefault(x => x.AppKey.Value == settingName);
            if (setting == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("key not found!");
            }
            else
                return setting.AppValue.Value;
        }
    }
```